# Oracle: Similar to sysdate but returning only time and only date

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I understand that Oracle sysdate returns the current date AND time. That's great for timestamp or datetime columns.

Now let's say I have a DATE only column. What keywords should I use on my insert query?

```
insert into myTable1(myDateOnlyColumn) values(???)
```

And let's say I have a TIME only column. What keywords should I use on my insert query?

```
 insert into myTable2(myTimeOnlyColumn) values(???)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no such thing as a DATE only column in Oracle. The DATE datatype stores date and time.

If you only care about the date, you can:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (dtCol) VALUES (TO_DATE('20110929','YYYYMMDD');
```

This leaves the time component at 00:00:00. You don't have to display it though.

If you're only interested in the time component, you still have a date stored in the column. You'll just have to handle that on output. For example:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE dt (d DATE);

SQL> INSERT INTO dt VALUES (TO_DATE('1:164800','J:HH24MISS'));

1 row inserted
```

Showing the actual contents of the column reveals a date was inserted:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM dt;

D
--------------------
0/0/0000 4:48:00 PM
```

Selecting only the time component from the column gives you the output you want:

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(d, 'HH24:MI:SS') d FROM dt;

D
--------
16:48:00

SQL>
```

If you think you need only a time column, you'll want to make sure you always insert the same date component.

Comment: So it stores all zeros for the time part when I am storing a birthdate? How about TIME only columns?

Comment: Good answer.  Also, if you have a date that includes hours, minutes and seconds: trunc(sysdate, 'd') to remove them rather than using TO_CHAR

Comment: @DCookie - Good answer.  I'd cover the INTERVAL data types, though, for storing times.  If you're only storing a time, you're generally storing a duration (i.e. 4 hours 48 minutes) which maps perfectly to an INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND rather than storing a time like 4:48 pm.

Comment: @DCookie: Why do you have to pass that 'J' in there? Can I just plug sysdate into these transformations to get the current date and current time?

Comment: @Sergio, you don't have to, I just used a julian date of 1 to get the year/month/day component to zeroes. Otherwise, you'll wind up with some sort of actual date in there, which, if you're trying to implement a "time only" column might confuse the issue.

Comment: @Sergio, it stores all zeroes for the time part if you omit the time. Doesn't matter if its a birthdate or a wedding anniversary date. If you specify a time, it stores a time. Again, there is no such thing as a "time only" column.

Answer (score 16):

To remove time from `sysdate` you can just write `TRUNC(sysdate)`.

For example:

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) "TODAY" FROM DUAL;
```

will give you:

```
TODAY                     
------------------------- 
'2012-10-02 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sysdate, to_date(to_char(sysdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy'),'dd/mm/yyyy') d
from dual
```

Comment: You need to explain why this code will resolve an Op's question already answered?

Answer (score 0):

For whoever is looking for a simple solution for returning only date without time, I found this:

```
to_date(SYSDATE,'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Works like a charm. ;-)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).