# Oracle current_date or sysdate without hours, minutes, seconds

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Is there any way to get rid of the time of day when using `current_date` or `sysdate`. I'm trying to only the store the date as `YYYY-MM-DD` , but current_date is giving me `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS:MS`

Or when comparing the dates, it only compares the date and not the time would be just as good. Any help would be awesome, thanks.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7604167/1065197

Comment: The time format `HH:MM:SS:MS` is wrong. `MM` stands for a numeric month (`MS` is also not recognized). It should be `HH:MI:SS`. If you need milliseconds, you need to use the `TIMESTAMP` data type, since Oracle stores only the fractions up to second in a `DATE` type field.

Comment: In Oracle the DATE datatype contains the fields YEAR, MONTH, DAY, HOURS, MINUTES, and SECONDS.  There is no datatype in Oracle for storing ONLY the YEAR, MONTH, and DAY fields.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Maybe you should try

```
trunc(sysdate)
```

function.

Comment: Stores the time as 00:00:00 but still works. Thanks.

Comment: Yes it remains date type but without the exact time itself.

Comment: what is the performance impact of this?

Answer (score 2):

Rusty answered the part of your question regarding stripping the time portion.  The part about incorporating the time when comparing dates is often done like this.

```
where YourDateField >= StartDate
and YourDateField < TheDayAfterEndDate
```

If you want to search on a specific date, StartDate and EndDate would be the same.

Comment: I really like `StartDate <= YourDateField and YourDateField < TheDayAfterEndDate` sort of like in math `x <= y < z`.