# getting date from oracle database without time from a column

Tags: java, javascript, sql, oracle, date

I want to get details from data base in which date is of format `08-MAR-14 03.52.17.000000000 PM` .I know its possible to get date

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE somecol >= '2011-01-01' AND somecol <= '2011-01-30'
```

in this data i am having time also  and  how is it possible to get only date and I am using java to connect with oracle and html5+java script+j query.

Comment: Use the `DATE()` function to extract the year-month-day part. E.g. `DATE(somecol) > '2011-01-01'`

Comment: ResultSet.getDate() will only not include the time portion of the data. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getDate(int)

Comment: What is the datatype of 'somecol'?

Comment: It sounds like you are applying conditions on this date as well. You could use trunc(col_date) for your conditions and to_char(col_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') for how the column values are presented in the select statement.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle: Similar to sysdate but returning only time and only date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604167/oracle-similar-to-sysdate-but-returning-only-time-and-only-date)

Comment: somecoln is timestamp

Answer (score 1):

use to_char function.

[Refer this link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2113.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming somecol contains the date field that is actually stored as a VARCHAR2 text string of the format:

```
08-MAR-14 03.52.17.000000000 PM
```

If this is the case, here's your query:

```
select * from table 
  where to_date(substr(somecol, 0, 9)) >= '01-JAN-11'
    and to_date(substr(somecol, 0, 9)) <= '30-JAN-11';
```

The problem with this is that Oracle needs to execute the substr and to_date on every row in order to know which ones to bring back.  If you need to run this frequently on a table with a large number of rows, it would impact your performance.  You could create function-based indexes on 'to_date(substr(somecol, 0, 9))' in order to lessen this impact.